# Prove a function is a branch of another multivalued function

Tags: complex-analysis

The question I am being asked to solve is: Prove the principal cube root function is a branch of the multivalued cube root $f(z)=\sqrt[3]{(z)}$

However, the definition my book gives is somewhat ambiguous (or I am bad at reading). The definition is as follows: A branch of $f$ is any single-valued function $f_0$ that is continuous in some domain (except, perhaps, on the boundary). At each point $z$ in the domain, it assigns one of the values of $f(z)$.

I am curious as to how to prove a function is a branch in general. Do you have to show that it is a single valued function and that it is continuous everywhere on its domain except the boundary of its domain?

The book is Complex Analysis for Mathematics and Engineering by John H. Mathews and Russel W. Howell 6th Edition

Answer (score 0):

The textbook definition is fine.

Let's say your principal cube root function is $f(x)=x$.

You need to prove:

1. For any $x=z$, exists one value of $f(z)$ that equals to $f(x)$.
2. $f(x)$ is continuous on the closed domain and differentiable on the open domain.

And you would mainly rely on the definition of principal cube root function.